# how to remove Strikethrough from Word Interop via C# app

Tags: c#, ms-word, strikethrough

Sorry if this is a remedial question, I did look all over and can't find the answer anywhere prior to posting.

I have a simple C# app that opens a MS Word document, looks at a 3 columns, and inserts into a database. This part works fine.

My problem is this: In some of the documents, some of the text has strikethrough. I want this removed. I have looked all over, and clearly I am missing something.

Specifically, the column with the issue is the one named `Graphicstext`. I just need to remove the strikethrough for that, I have tried some things, but I really have no idea what to do. Thank you in advance.

```
foreach(Table tb in docs.Tables) {
    //for (int row = 1; row <= tb.Rows.Count; row++)

    int ColumnCount = tb.Columns.Count;

    for (int row = 1; row <= tb.Rows.Count; row++) {
        PageCell = tb.Cell(row, 1);
        EnglishTextCell = tb.Cell(row, 2);
        TranslationsCell = tb.Cell(row, 3);
        GlossaryCell = tb.Cell(row, 4);
        //GraphicsCell = tb.Cell(row, 5);
        GraphicsCell = tb.Cell(row, ColumnCount);

        string Pagetext = PageCell.Range.Text;
        Pagetext = stripCellText(Pagetext);

        string Englishtext = EnglishTextCell.Range.Text.ToString();
        Englishtext = NewLineCellText(Englishtext);

        string Translationtext = TranslationsCell.Range.Text.ToString();
        Translationtext = stripCellText(Translationtext);

        string Glossarytext = GlossaryCell.Range.Text.ToString();
        Glossarytext = stripCellText(Glossarytext);

        string Graphicstext = GraphicsCell.Range.Text.ToString();
        Graphicstext = stripCellText(Graphicstext);


        string filenametouse = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath);

        string file1 = filenametouse.Substring(0, 3);
        string file2 = filenametouse.Substring(3, 2);
        string file3 = file1 + "-" + file2;

        //MessageBox.Show("row should be: " + Pagetext + " " + Englishtext + " " + Translationtext + " " + Glossarytext + " " + Graphicstext);
        //wfile.WriteLine("row should be: " + Pagetext + "|" + Englishtext + "|" + Translationtext + "|" + Glossarytext + "|" + Graphicstext );
        wfile.WriteLine("row should be: " + file3 + "|" + Pagetext + "|" + Englishtext + "|" + Graphicstext);
        wfile.WriteLine("");

        string cmdText = "INSERT INTO Lesson_Info(LessonName,PageNumber,EnglishText,Graphics)VALUES(@lesson,@pagetext,@Englishtext,@Graphicstext)";

        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand cmd = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(cmdText, conn);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lesson", file3);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pagetext", Pagetext);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Englishtext", Englishtext);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Graphicstext", Graphicstext);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        //wfile.WriteLine("row should be: " + Pagetext);
    }
}

public string stripCellText(string text) {
    return text.Replace("\r\a", "");
    //return text.Replace("\n", "");
}
```

Comment: Its been a while since I've used the Word API, but can you do something like GraphicsCell.Range.Select(); then docs.Selection.Font.Strikethrough = false;

Comment: I did end up solving this. Really what I wanted was to not see formatted changes or revisions. docs.ActiveWindow.View.ShowFormatChanges = false;docs.ActiveWindow.View.ShowRevisionsAndComments = false; where docs is:  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document docs = word.Documents.Open(ref path, ref miss, ref readOnly, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss);